# Filter by grouping two columns and sum third column data python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sum

I have an assignment to do for college, 
where I need to write a python code that lists years, total won, 
and total lost of bets that took place.

My data is in a .csv file with headings

```
Race_Course
Horse Name
Year
Month
Day
Amount_won_lost
Win/Los
```

I need to print out the following:

```
Year        Total Won   Total Lost
2016        €xxxxx      €xxxxx
2017        €xxxxx      €xxxxx
```

I have tried the following:

```
total = df.groupby(['Year','Win/Loss']).Amount_won_lost.sum().reset_index(level=1)
print(total)
```

which prints:

```
Year       Win/Loss     Amount_won_lost
2016.0     lost         115.00
2016.0     won          584.81
2017.0     lost         5.00
2017.0     won          69.31
```

How do I rearrange the total won and total lost for each year?

Comment: this is called a pivot in pandas

Answer (score 0):

Added this to the end and it worked:

```
print(total_won_2016.pivot(index=None, columns='Win/Loss', values='Amount_won_lost'))
```